# Zend 2.0 - navigation rendersubmenu + partial

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2, partial, submenu

How to "->renderSubMenu()" using setPartial?

```
<?php $this->navigation('Navigation')->menu()->setPartial(array('menu.phtml', 'default')); ?>
```

and when I use

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('Navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

In output I have all menu, but I want to get the same menu output as in '->renderSubMenu()'.

I hope that everyone will understand my needs.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
     echo $this->navigation('Navigation')
      ->menu()
      ->setPartial(array('menu.phtml', 'default'))
      ->renderSubMenu()
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo $this->navigation($this->navigation('Navigation')->getChildren())
        ->menu()
        ->setPartial(array('menu.phtml', 'default'));
?>
```